# Why can I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XXXXCustomizer or XXXXXBeanInfo

Tags: java

the blow  just a piece of log,The class for build logback is found, Why do it need to find other class, which append subfix `BeanInfo` or `Customizer` , Where is it from? and How should I resovle this issue?

```
15:29:34.185 [main] DEBUG c.i.n.classloader.NetworkClassLoader - M[loadClass]:found the Class [ch.qos.logback.core.sift.SiftingAppenderBase] by the super.findClass[JHeart]
15:29:34.187 [main] DEBUG c.i.n.classloader.NetworkClassLoader - ***M[loadClass]:found the Class [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender] by the super.findClass[JHeart]***
15:29:34,189 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SIFT]
......
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender*BeanInfo*
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)**
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1059)
    at com.iotex.network.classloader.NetworkClassLoader.loadClass(NetworkClassLoader.java:187)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:103)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(InstanceFinder.java:93)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(InstanceFinder.java:66)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Introspector.java:438)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:388)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.introspect(PropertySetter.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.getMethod(PropertySetter.java:393)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.findAdderMethod(PropertySetter.java:203)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.computeAggregationType(PropertySetter.java:177)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.isApplicable(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:61)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.lookupImplicitAction(Interpreter.java:237)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.getApplicableActionList(Interpreter.java:256)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:144)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:129)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:76)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:68)
    at com.iotex.jheart.core.Platform.resetLoggerFactory(Platform.java:165)
    at com.iotex.jheart.core.Platform.configLogback(Platform.java:152)
    at com.iotex.jheart.core.management.ModuleManager.loadTargetModules(ModuleManager.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.iotex.jheart.one.JHeart.startup(JHeart.java:522)
    at com.iotex.jheart.one.JHeart.main(JHeart.java:787)
```

Comment: Did you add all jars ?

Comment: have a look in to link http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html

Comment: I think that is about Java Bean Interface , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html,I just want to stop the ClassNotFoundException , not implement it!